# Is the number of entries $n$ of a vector $\vec v = \big(v_1, v_2, \ldots, v_n\big)$ in a vector space $V$ equal to $\dim(V)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Is the number of entries $n$ of a vector $\vec v = \big(v_1, v_2, \ldots, v_n\big)$ in a vector space $V$ equal to $\dim(V)$? For example, take the vector space $P_3$, the set of polynomials of degree $3$ or less. It can be characterised by (or is isomorphic to?) the vector
$$\vec p = \big(a, b, c, d\big) \text{ for any polynomial } ax^3 + bx^2 +cx + d$$
Since the number of entries of $\vec p$ is $4$, does it follow that $\dim(P_3) = 4$. This question is more referring to the general case, not $P_3$, which I already know has dimension $4$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not quite, as @paulinho pointed out. The dimension of a vector space V is determined by how many basis vectors span the space, that is, the minimum number of vectors from which any linear combination of them can create any vector in the field.

For $R^{n}$ and $P_{n-1}$ it is true that the number of entries in the vector corresponds to the dimension of the vector space but this is not true in general.

Consider the vector space corresponding to the x-axis on a coordinate plane. We can write all such vectors in the form of $\begin{pmatrix}{n}\\{0}\end{pmatrix}$ , but since they are spanned by the single vector $\begin{pmatrix}{1}\\{0}\end{pmatrix}$, the dimension of this space is $1$, which makes sense because the x-axis is a number line.

---

However, *length* isn't normally a term used for # of entries of a vector.

Comment: Isn't length normally used to denote inner product?

Comment: Yeah, I thought so too, it would denote $\sqrt{<p,p>}$ but i'm not sure i should elaborate on it for OP

Comment: Thank you, I changed the question.

Comment: This is not correct? $\text{dim}(V)$ is the number of linearly independent elements that span $V$. All we can say is that $V$ is contained in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: @paulinho oops let me edit my answer

Comment: In short, don’t confuse the dimension of the ambient space with the dimension of the vector space being discussed.

Answer (score 3):

No. For example, if $V= \operatorname{sp} \{ (1,1) \}$, then $V$ has dimension one, but the number of elements in any point is two.

Comment: One could argue that this is just a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^2$, and their question is referring to the ambient space (not saying I am).

Comment: There is no mention of ambient space. The dimension of the vector space of symmetric matrices is ${ 1 \over 2} n (n+1)$, but it is typically represented as a point in $\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$.

Comment: Fair enough, and nice example!

Answer (score 0):

Generally, the dimension of a vector space is equal to the number of basis vectors (vectors that span the space).

Here is an example of a vector space where the above does not hold:

$$\mathbf{0}_3 = (0,0,0)^T.$$  The vector space $\{(0,0,0)^T\}$ has dimension $0$.

Comment: See my comment on Saketh Malyala's answer

Comment: Okay, the first part was not so relevant.  Cleaned it up a bit by removing that.  Thanks.